# What's the difference using RS485 or tcp/ip connection?

Tags: ethernet-port

Are there any differences to connect a Raspberry Pi to a BU unit via TCP/IP or RS-485?

I'm trying to connect the raspberry pi to this, to unlock a lock: [Intelligence storage Locker control module/ Lock control board system](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Intelligence-storage-Locker-control-module-Lock_60424226603.html?spm=a2700.details.pronpeci14.7.65ef5773zFHXkL)

If I were to use TCP/IP connection from the Raspberry Pi to the BU unit, can the Raspberry Pi still connect to the internet?

I'm using a Raspberry Pi model 3+

Comment: TCP/IP is indeed different from RS-485, and it is possible to connect to several IP network segments at the same time. You should outline your specific problem more clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(guessing from info in link) The "BU unit" appears to connect to the "CU units" (which actually control the locks) through RS 485, which sounds a like a interface which could be using a proprietary protocol similar to serial.

The Pi connects via TCP/IP (i.e. relatively normal internet) to the BU unit (see [diagram on the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4b0d.jpg), and [its description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Hykk.png)) - no idea what the software is (could be web interface, or commands have to be sent to the port from software on the PC/Pi).

If the Pi ethernet jack is connected to the BU board you can still connect to the internet through another interface like the onboard WiFi adapter, or through a [USB adapter](https://elinux.org/RPi_USB_Ethernet_adapters). You can also get network switches (like on internet routers) to 'split' the ethernet connection, though then the BU unit would likely then be on the wider network (which is often a less secure idea, though for secure locks WiFi may not be the best either!).